# Best way of saving current user data in CloudBoost

Tags: cloudboost

To retrieve the current logged user is as easy as call CB.CloudUser.current but, if I change some data of this user, which is the best way of saving it back to DataBase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you modified the current user.

```
CB.CloudUser.current.save({
//callback functions here..
});
```

Let me know if this help.

Comment: Yes! after doing CB.CloudUser.current.set('Column', 'value').